# Dependent variable is the amount of remittances in a survey

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, continuous-data

My thesis is on the microeconomic and macroeconomic determinants of remittances, and i am doing the research by using primary data taken directly from the expatriates who are working abroad.My dependent variable is the amount of remittances coming to the country. Most of the papers that i have gone through have discreet dependent variables or have categorized their dependent variable. I don't want to lose the information, therefore i wish to use the exact amount of remittances which is being sent by the expatriates as my dependent variable. Can i use it for my regression? My independent variables are discreet, and can you please also suggest appropriate models which i could use to analyze my survey set?  I am trying to see whether self interest, altruism,self insurance etc have an impact on the amount of remittances sent by the expatriates.

Comment: Are your IVs binary or just integer valued?

Comment: my IVs are measured on an ordinal scale from 1-5. They aren't binary\